# Word for a large facility that produces and distributes baked goods

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

I am translating a document into English, and I need to find the word for a large facility that produces and distributes baked goods (wholesale, to distributors).

Can I use the word "bakery"? To me, this invokes a bakery on a city street that sells bread and cakes to individual customers. Are there better words for this?

Comment: A bakery can be a small closet or an enormous factory.

Comment: If you need to distinguish it, call it a commercial or industrial bakery. Or just a factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bakery](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bakery) refers to:

> - A place where products such as bread, cake, and pastries are baked or sold. Also called bakeshop. (AHD).

To refer to the production and warehouse processes, I think you can use the expression:

***Bakery production facility.***

> *Bakery Production [Facility](http://www.amanabuildings.com/industries/food-processing/bakery-production-facility-for-dunkin-donuts-at-sharjah-industrial-area/)* for D.....’ Donuts at Sharjah Industrial Area
>
> - Located at the Sharjah Industrial Area, this kitchen and warehouse is the largest doughnut production facility outside the United States.